# Add new column, multiply value with strings with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Some how I can't wrap my head around a simple question. How do I count the number of string values in `sentiment` times (*) the integer in another column `times_used`. Probably with `group_by()` and `summarise()`? With the following dataframe:

```
        word times_used sentiment
       <chr>      <int>     <chr>
 1      fake         68  negative
 2       bad         36  negative
 3 president         35  positive
 4       tax         32  negative
 5   failing         21  negative
 6      vote         20  negative
 7      vote         20  positive
 8      deal         19  positive
 9       job         19  positive
10    united         19  positive
# ... with 475 more rows
```

Eventually looking for something like this:

```
times_used sentiment
     <int>     <chr>
      4090  negative
      3198  positive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would want something like:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 group_by(sentiment) %>%
 summarise(count = n(),
           words = sum(times_used)) %>%
 mutate(total = count * words)
#  A tibble: 2 x 4
#  sentiment count words total
#     <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
#1  negative     5   177   885
#2  positive     5   112   560
```

And then you can chain `select(sentiment, total)` if you just want those two columns.